# How to fit two/+ background images?

Tags: html, css

Hello I've done this: http://inventors.000webhostapp.com
and the thing is I'd like to make each background image fit the entire screen.
For that matter I searched and found this:

```css
html { 
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/370799/pexels-photo-370799.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>  
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

that made 1 of the pictures fit all the screen but my problem comes when I want to add a second one.
What I did is create

```css
.p1 { 
  background: url(1.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.p2{
  background: url(2.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>  
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="p1">
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
 <div class="p2">
 <p>hello</p>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

That makes the background images just tiny (the height of hello)

Here comes the question: 
Is there any way to make those 2 images fit all the screen one after the other?

So I would see all the first image when I open the WebPage and when I scroll all the way to the bottom I would see entirely the second image?
Obviously I plan to put more than 2 background images for my portfolio but this is a good way, I think, to start with!

Comment: `background-size: cover;` only relates to how the image will be fit to the element it's applied to. The problem in your example is that the element which have the background are really small while in the first example it was applied to the whole html.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Axnyff in the comments `background-size:cover` only affects the way the background fills the containing element. In order to make these elements fill the screen you can use the `vh` [viewport height unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length).

```css
body, p {
    margin: 0;
}

.p1, .p2 {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
}

.p1 { 
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/1/);
}

.p2{
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/2/);
}
```

```html
<div class="p1">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
<div class="p2">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

One `vh` unit is equal to 1% of the viewport height hence the use of `100vh` in my example to fill the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the size for your container. You can set the viewport size for the container with `100vh` (height) and `100vw` (width). See the following example:

```css
html, body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.p1 p, .p2 p {
  display:inline-block;
}
.p1 { 
  background: url(http://placehold.it/100x100) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
.p2{
  background: url(http://placehold.it/101x101) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="p1">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
<div class="p2">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```